# At run time how to I verify that the database schema matches my objects?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have data access object that have been generated by SqlMetal, however the database is created by running a sql script.

Is there an easy way to verify that all table and columns names and type matches the attributes on the classes that SqlMetal created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the easiest way to do this would be to have some kind of version number hidden in a config table in your schema. Then on runtime check the version number returned.

Much easier than doing a full scan.  Set the version number in your SQL script and somewhere in your data access object

Comment: This is what I was writing... With the slight difference that I usually use an extended property of the DB to store the schema version.

Comment: Given that Link-to-sql can create the database tables it's self from the classes and mapping attributes, I was hoping that Link-to-sql could check that the mapping and database were compactable with each other.

Comment: I left LINQ2SQL and went to PLINQO for this reason.